# pandas cut with infinite upper/lower bounds

Tags: python, pandas

The [pandas `cut()` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) states that: "Out of bounds values will be NA in the resulting Categorical object." This makes it difficult when the upper bound is not necessarily clear or important. For example:

```
cut (weight, bins=[10,50,100,200])
```

Will produce the bins:

```
[(10, 50] < (50, 100] < (100, 200]]
```

So `cut (250, bins=[10,50,100,200])` will produce a `NaN`, as will `cut (5, bins=[10,50,100,200])`. What I'm trying to do is produce something like `> 200` for the first example and `< 10` for the second.

I realize I could do `cut (weight, bins=[float("inf"),10,50,100,200,float("inf")])` or the equivalent, but the report style I am following doesn't allow things like `(200, inf]`. I realize too I could actually specify custom labels via the `labels` parameter on `cut()`, but that means remembering to adjust them every time I adjust `bins`, which could be often.

Have I exhausted all the possibilities, or is there something in `cut()` or elsewhere in `pandas` that would help me do this? I'm thinking about writing a wrapper function for `cut()` that would automatically generate the labels in desired format from the bins, but I wanted to check here first.

Comment: Are you asking about how to set the bin boundaries, or how to label one as "200+"?  You could just set the upper boundary to `the_data.max()+1` or something, but I think you'll have to set the label manually if you want that specific format.

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to think it's the only way.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use `float("inf")` as the upper bound and `-float("inf")` as the lower bound in the bins list. It will remove NaN values.

Comment: pd.cut(df.duration, [0,5,10,20,float("inf")],right=True)

Comment: Long overdue, am making this the accepted answer!

Comment: `np.inf` (as per another answer) is basically the same

Answer (score 13):

After waiting a few days, still no answers posted - I think that's probably because there really is no way around this other than writing the `cut()` wrapper function.  I am posting my version of it here and marking the question as answered.  I will change that if new answers come along.

```
def my_cut (x, bins,
            lower_infinite=True, upper_infinite=True,
            **kwargs):
    r"""Wrapper around pandas cut() to create infinite lower/upper bounds with proper labeling.

    Takes all the same arguments as pandas cut(), plus two more.

    Args :
        lower_infinite (bool, optional) : set whether the lower bound is infinite
            Default is True. If true, and your first bin element is something like 20, the
            first bin label will be '<= 20' (depending on other cut() parameters)
        upper_infinite (bool, optional) : set whether the upper bound is infinite
            Default is True. If true, and your last bin element is something like 20, the
            first bin label will be '> 20' (depending on other cut() parameters)
        **kwargs : any standard pandas cut() labeled parameters

    Returns :
        out : same as pandas cut() return value
        bins : same as pandas cut() return value
    """

    # Quick passthru if no infinite bounds
    if not lower_infinite and not upper_infinite:
        return pd.cut(x, bins, **kwargs)

    # Setup
    num_labels      = len(bins) - 1
    include_lowest  = kwargs.get("include_lowest", False)
    right           = kwargs.get("right", True)

    # Prepend/Append infinities where indiciated
    bins_final = bins.copy()
    if upper_infinite:
        bins_final.insert(len(bins),float("inf"))
        num_labels += 1
    if lower_infinite:
        bins_final.insert(0,float("-inf"))
        num_labels += 1

    # Decide all boundary symbols based on traditional cut() parameters
    symbol_lower  = "<=" if include_lowest and right else "<"
    left_bracket  = "(" if right else "["
    right_bracket = "]" if right else ")"
    symbol_upper  = ">" if right else ">="

    # Inner function reused in multiple clauses for labeling
    def make_label(i, lb=left_bracket, rb=right_bracket):
        return "{0}{1}, {2}{3}".format(lb, bins_final[i], bins_final[i+1], rb)

    # Create custom labels
    labels=[]
    for i in range(0,num_labels):
        new_label = None

        if i == 0:
            if lower_infinite:
                new_label = "{0} {1}".format(symbol_lower, bins_final[i+1])
            elif include_lowest:
                new_label = make_label(i, lb="[")
            else:
                new_label = make_label(i)
        elif upper_infinite and i == (num_labels - 1):
            new_label = "{0} {1}".format(symbol_upper, bins_final[i])
        else:
            new_label = make_label(i)

        labels.append(new_label)

    # Pass thru to pandas cut()
    return pd.cut(x, bins_final, labels=labels, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Great!. Have you proposed your code for the next Pandas version?

Comment: Wow, I never thought to do that.  I think I will try - thanks!

Comment: This is not necessary. As other answers have pointed, you can just use np.inf, or float("inf") or math.inf as the boundary.

Answer (score 10):

just add `np.inf`, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.cut(df['weight'], [0, 50, 100, np.inf], labels=['0-50', '50-100', '100-'])
```

Comment: Just a headsup that you might want to consider `include_lowest=True` to make the first interval `[0, 50]` instead of `(0, 50]`